# How to target text fragment on page with that fragment as param on URL

Tags: url, parameters, anchor

About a week ago I learned that you could add text segments to a URL and jump to that text on a page.  I didn't even notice at first until I looked at the URL of a page that came up in a search and noticed the text segment I was linked to was added to the URL (not an ID, it was a fragment of text that matched exactly).

But apparently I have learned nothing in my years of programming because I thought it was pretty cool but I did not write down the syntax.  It worked the same as if there would have been an ID in the URL as a parameter, except it was a fragment of text.

**How do you link to a text segment on a page as a parameter?**

I swear I remember it being something like `www.google.com/?~#texthere` but I can't find an example, or the page in my history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I was able to get the search terms correct to get a result and found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989058/how-does-text-in-url-works-to-highlight-text) on stackoverflow.

What I was looking for is apparently Google Chrome specific.

```
/#:~:text=
```